# why can't I call a function inside my graphql resolvers

Tags: javascript, async-await, graphql

I am trying to call multiple aysnc await within my graphql resolver which keep telling my my **Promise or function** is not a function. So I tried to call a regular function withe the same result. I even try passing the function via the connector vs just an import and still the same result...here is a example of the code snippet:

```
import { clientdb, driver, fse } from './connectors';
 .    
..
...
....

createClient: async(parent, args, { Client }) => {

const singleclient = await new clientdb(args.client).save(); //this line works
const spawndb = await new fse.copy('c:/databases/default.graphdb', 'c:/databases/dbName.graphdb'); //this gives an error
},

TypeError: Cannot read property 'copy' of undefined
    at _callee3$ (C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/GenysisGQL/server/resolvers.js:150:39)
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\GenysisGQL\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:65:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\GenysisGQL\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:299:22)
```

clientdb is the mongodb driver imported from ./connectors

```
const clientdb = mongoose.model('client', clientSchema);
```

fse.copy is from fs-extra

```
let orgCode = getHashKey(org, max);  //this is a regular function...same error

TypeError: (0 , _gethashkey.gethashkey) is not a function
    at _callee3$ (C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/GenysisGQL/server/resolvers.js:158:23)
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\GenysisGQL\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:65:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\GenysisGQL\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:299:22)
```

I did do a TypeOf check and my function is no longer a function one inside the Aysnc. The question is why are these no longer functions while the mongoDB driver is ok. why are they treated differently?

Comment: This is not a minimal, complete, verifiable example. That means I can't copy/paste it myself and see the error. Have you tried "downgrading" from async/await to using explicit Promises to see what's going on?

Comment: @ed...I did downgrade to a promise(the fse is a promise) i get he same error...property copy undefined....also I used just the plain function gethashkey(x,y) and got he error shown in the question...sorry I can't show you enough to reproduce the error...but what I have here I believe are the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I was terrible misled by the fs-extra docs.....fs-extra isn't a promise after all. One have to use fs-extra-plus or fs-extra-promise-es6. Found this out after many hours then start to doubt the docs.